# How can I show that the rank of a matrix is not altered if a column is multiplied by a non-zero scalar?

Tags: matrices

How can I show that the rank of a matrix is not altered if a column is multiplied by a non-zero scalar? I don't know where to start.

Comment: this is the effect of multipplying on the right by a square matrix, the identity except one diagonal element is replaced by your non-zero scalar

Comment: @Will Jagy I didn't get it.

Comment: rank = dim of column space

Answer (score 0):

The dimension of the space spanned by the row vectors [is the same](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1900437/proof-that-the-dimension-of-a-matrix-row-space-is-equal-to-the-dimension-of-its) as that spanned by its column vectors.  Let $C = \{c_1, \dots, c_n\}$ be the collection of $n$ column vectors.  Its span is unchanged if we multiply one of the $c_i$ by a nonzero scalar.  So whether you define rank using rows or columns, you have not changed the rank.